# filter wpf datagrid values from a textbox

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I have a  textbox and a Datagrid. The datagrid has two columns  name  and Email address. I want to Filter the datagrid values with the value in the textbox.[image]

Comment: By which column, Name or Email? And are you using MVVM design pattern here?

Comment: @Colin ,how to do this in MVVM

Answer (score 29):

You can use a `ICollectionView` for the `DataGrid` `ItemSource` then you can apply a `Filter` predicate and refesh the list when needed.

Here is a very quick example.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="188" Width="288" Name="UI" >
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridCollection}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication10
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ICollectionView _dataGridCollection;
        private string _filterString;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataGridCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TestData);
            DataGridCollection.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);
        }

        public ICollectionView DataGridCollection
        {
            get { return _dataGridCollection; }
            set { _dataGridCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DataGridCollection"); }
        }

        public string FilterString
        {
            get { return _filterString; }
            set 
            {
                _filterString = value; 
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");
                FilterCollection();
            }
        }

        private void FilterCollection()
        {
            if (_dataGridCollection != null)
            {
                _dataGridCollection.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public bool Filter(object obj)
        {
            var data = obj as TestClass;
            if (data != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filterString))
                {
                    return data.Name.Contains(_filterString) || data.Email.Contains(_filterString);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TestClass> TestData
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestClass { Name = "1", Email = "1@test.com" };
                yield return new TestClass { Name = "2", Email = "2@test.com" };
                yield return new TestClass { Name = "3", Email = "3@test.com" };
                yield return new TestClass { Name = "4", Email = "4@test.com" };
                yield return new TestClass { Name = "5", Email = "5@test.com" };
                yield return new TestClass { Name = "6", Email = "6@test.com" };
                yield return new TestClass { Name = "7", Email = "7@test.com" };
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image] [image]

Comment: Can we do this in mvvm

Comment: Not that it matters, but you can simply the last method to.
`PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`