# Display and Filter XML Data in WPF Application

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, filter

I am creating a very simple WPF application that loads data from an XML file and displays it as a table.  However, I need to have the table free-text filterable (by any value, any column).  The problem is that the XML data will have **an unknown number of attributes**, so I can't cast the data to a known/concrete object (note that for any given XML file, the number of attributes will always be the same).

I originally tried the code from **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099042/filter-wpf-datagrid-values-from-a-textbox)**, but found that since I can't cast my XML data to a known object, that I can't use the Filter predicate method on the DataGridCollectionView (the CanFilter method is set to false when I pass in my DataSet).  Therefore, I found that I have to use BindingListCollectionView which accepts a CustomFilter, but it's a "klunky" SQL type filter.

Here's a random XML file that works for this purpose.

```
<products>
  <product Name="Widget" Amount="123.45" Size="10 in" SomeOtherValue="foo" />
  <product Name="Screw" Amount="8.52" Size="5.1 cm" SomeOtherValue="bar" />
  <product Name="Bolt" Amount="2.66" Size="4 in" SomeOtherValue="con" />
  <product Name="Hinge" Amount="14.00" Size="22 cm" SomeOtherValue="toso" />
</products>
```

**The following code works** (somewhat), but it seems really dirty.  Also, it acts weird in that if I provide an invalid filter value of "xxx", no results are returned (normal), but then for "xxxx" all the results are returned, and again for "xxxxx", no results are returned.  It's the **FilterString** method I need help with. How can I clean up this code and eliminate my abnormal filter behavior?

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private BindingListCollectionView _bindingListCollection;
    private string _filterString;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(@"D:\index.xml");
        BindingListCollection = (BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
        BindingListCollection.CustomFilter = null;
    }

    public BindingListCollectionView BindingListCollection
    {
        get { return _bindingListCollection; }
        set { _bindingListCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("BindingListCollection"); }
    }

    public string FilterString
    {
        get { return _filterString; }
        set
        {
            _filterString = value;
            if (_bindingListCollection == null) return;
            var filterValue = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataRowView dataRowView in _bindingListCollection.SourceCollection)
            {
                // Loop through each column in the underlying data and manually create a SQL filter
                foreach (var columnName in dataRowView.DataView.DataViewManager.DataSet.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    filterValue += string.Format("{0} LIKE '%" + _filterString + "%' OR ", columnName);
                }
                // I don't want to iterate through the rows, I just need to get to the raw table columns, so I break here
                break; 
            }

            if (filterValue == string.Empty)
            {
                BindingListCollection.CustomFilter = null;
            }
            else
            {
                // add something so the last "OR" doesn't throw things off
                BindingListCollection.CustomFilter = filterValue + " 0 = 1";
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");
            _bindingListCollection.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property)); }
    }

}
```

If you want it to help troubleshoot, here's also the presentation code

```
<Window x:Class="MyViewer.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="368" Width="1002" Name="UI" >
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BindingListCollection}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I think you can just use a `ObservableCollection<DataRow>`, and filter the `DataSet` using `DataRow.ItemArray`. Something like:</strike>

I'll query the raw data using LINQ which generate the result as `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, and then convert it to `DataTable` for the view to bind with use `DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable` Method.

```
//Warning not tested.....

public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private DataSet _dataSet;
private string _filterString;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _dataSet = new DataSet();
    _dataSet.ReadXml(@"D:\index.xml");
    FilterString=null;

}

public DataTable BindingListCollection
{
    get {
         return FilteredList.CopyToDataTable();
        }
}

public IEnumerable<DataRow> FilteredList
{
    get {
         //may need to check _dataSet is not null 
         return  string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterString)?                        
                    from DataRow dr in _dataSet.Tables[0].Rows select dr
                   :from DataRow dr in _dataSet.Tables[0].Rows
                         where dr.ItemArray.Count(c => c.ToString().IndexOf(FilterString,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)>=0) > 0
                         select dr;
        }
}

public string FilterString
{
    get { return _filterString; }
    set
    {
        _filterString = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("BindingListCollection");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property)); }
}

}
```

Comment: Bolu, I like your idea, but I can't seem to get it to work.  First, I had to move `InitializeComponent()` to after the population of the _dataSet.  Then, when the DataTable is displayed, it doesn't display the data from the XML.  Instead it is displaying Columns for RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray and HasErrors.  This looks like the `BindingListCollection` property is returning the metadata for the _dataTable, but not the values themselves.  I think the `ItemArray` property in this object contains the values I'm looking for, but I don't know how to return them.  What am I missing?

Comment: @bigmac, you could convert the result list back to a `DataTable` and use that as the `ItemsSource` in your `DataGrid`. I'll update shortly.

Comment: @bigmac, updated my answer, basically, you need to query your row data using LINQ and generate the result as `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, and then convert it to `DataTable` for the view use `DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable Method`.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is a bit killer code, let me offer you an alternative:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(@"D:\temp\my.xml");

var defaultView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);

/*
    Operator LIKE is used to include only values that match a pattern with wildcards. 
    Wildcard character is * or %, it can be at the beginning of a pattern '*value', at the end 'value*', or at both '*value*'. 
    Wildcard in the middle of a patern 'va*lue' is not allowed.
*/
Func<string, string> escapeLike = valueWithoutWildcards => {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < valueWithoutWildcards.Length; i++)
  {
    char c = valueWithoutWildcards[i];
    if (c == '*' || c == '%' || c == '[' || c == ']')
      sb.Append("[").Append(c).Append("]");
    else if (c == '\'')
      sb.Append("''");
    else
      sb.Append(c);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
};


var w = new Window();
w.Loaded += (o,e) => {

    var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    var myButton = new Button();
    myButton.Content = "Click me!";
    myButton.Click += delegate { 

        var userQueryString = "screw";

        // todo; you might want to escape dataColumn.ColumnName, but not sure
        var finalQueryList = new List<string>();
        foreach(DataColumn dataColumn in defaultView.Table.Columns)
            finalQueryList.Add(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", 
                 dataColumn.ColumnName, escapeLike(userQueryString)));

        defaultView.RowFilter = string.Join(" OR ", finalQueryList); 
    };

    stackPanel.Children.Add(new DataGrid() { ItemsSource = defaultView });
    stackPanel.Children.Add(myButton);

    w.Content = stackPanel;
};


w.Show();

new Application().Run(w);
```

ps that code is just to demonstrate few things:

- I don't see reason why would you even need to fiddle with BindingListCollection, it's one fugly mothe..
- You need to be aware that user can type different characters which will break the "SQL-like" queries. To understand what you need to take care of: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/ I've already implemented a bit of it, to demonstrate.
- No need to refresh defaultView, it's always kept "up-to-date"
- The "OR" magic trick is not nice (**0=1**).
- If you're going to use string.Format, then stick with it. No alternating.

Comment: Chris, thank you for your example and direction.  I am going to accept Bolu's answer as it feels the cleanest to me and allowed me to integrate it into my current code the easiest.  However, I really like the concepts you presented an how you are creating delegates for the features.  Thank you again for the time you put into this.