# Filtering a WPF Datagrid with a Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm making this application that pulls data from a Sharepoint site using XML Node,

```
private XmlNode GetListItems(string listTitle)
    {
        var client = new Bluejeanware.MWELS.Lists();
        System.Net.NetworkCredential passCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        client.Credentials = passCredentials;
        return client.GetListItems(listTitle, string.Empty, null, null, string.Empty, null, null);
    }

    public void BindSPDataSource()
    {
        var data = GetListItems("Tasks");
        var result = XElement.Parse(data.OuterXml);
        XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
        var taskItems = from r in result.Descendants(z + "row")
                        select new
                        {
                            TaskName = r.Attribute("ows_LinkTitle").Value,
                            DueDate = r.Attribute("ows_DueDate") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_DueDate").Value : string.Empty,
                            AssignedTo = r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo").Value : string.Empty,
                        };

        dataGridView.ItemsSource = taskItems;
    }
```

I'd like to filter the data being pulled with a Textbox, a good example of what it should be is this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099042/filter-wpf-datagrid-values-from-a-textbox) post

I'm having a hard time on transitioning this code into a way that it would work with the way my application is adding the data to my Datagrid, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to:

- retrieve list data from SharePoint via SharePoint Web Services
- bind to DataGrid and enable filtering

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SPO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Tasks" Width="800px" Height="600px" Name="TasksWindow">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TasksWindow}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItemCollection}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace SPO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListItemCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(LoadTasks());
            ListItemCollection.Filter = FilterTask;
        }


        public bool FilterTask(object value)
        {
            var entry = value as TaskEntry;
            if (entry != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filterString))
                {
                    return entry.TaskName.Contains(_filterString);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Bind SP Data Source 
        /// </summary>
        private IEnumerable<TaskEntry> LoadTasks()
        {
            var data = GetListItems("http://intranet.contoso.com","Tasks");
            var result = XElement.Parse(data.OuterXml);
            XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
            var taskItems = from r in result.Descendants(z + "row")
                            select new TaskEntry
                                {
                                    TaskName = r.Attribute("ows_LinkTitle").Value,
                                    DueDate = r.Attribute("ows_DueDate") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_DueDate").Value : string.Empty,
                                    AssignedTo = r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo").Value : string.Empty,
                                };
            return taskItems;
         }


        private XmlNode GetListItems(string webUri,string listTitle)
        {
            var client = new Lists.Lists();
            client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
            return client.GetListItems(listTitle, string.Empty, null, null, string.Empty, null, null);
        }



        public ICollectionView ListItemCollection
        {
            get { return _listItemCollection; }
            set { _listItemCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ListItemCollection"); }
        }




        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public string FilterString
        {
            get { return _filterString; }
            set
            {
                _filterString = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");
                if (_listItemCollection != null)
                {
                    _listItemCollection.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }


        private ICollectionView _listItemCollection;
        private string _filterString;

    }

    public class TaskEntry
    {
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string DueDate { get; set; }
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

-First define a `TaskItem` class to hold the properties of each node in your `OuterXml`.

-Make sure your `ViewModel` (or your codebehind if the `DataContext` is set to it) implements the `INorifyPropertyChanged` Interface to propagate the changes in the properties to the UI).

-Then turn your `taskItems` into an `ObservableCollection` Property of the `TaskItem` class, and define the filter property as well which is bond to the filter TextBox.

here is the full code

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Populate the TaskItems collection using BindSPDataSource() method

    }
    private String _filter = String.Empty;
    public String Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return _filter;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_filter == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _filter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            TaskItems = new ObservableCollection<TaskItem>(TaskItems.Where(x => x.AssignedTo.ToLower().Contains(_filter) ||
                x.DueDate.ToLower().Contains(_filter) ||
                x.TaskName.ToLower().Contains(_filter)
                ));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TaskItem> _taskItem;
    public ObservableCollection<TaskItem> TaskItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _taskItem;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_taskItem == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _taskItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public class TaskItem
{
    public String TaskName { get; set; }
    public String DueDate { get; set; }
    public String AssignedTo { get; set; }
}
```

and the Xaml:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Filter,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TaskItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

and don't forget to set the `DataContext` :

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

and Finally in the constructor don't populate the `DataGrid` `ItemSource` Directly, change this in the `BindSPDataSource()` method :
  dataGridView.ItemsSource = taskItems;
to something like this :

```
 TaskItems=new ObservableCollection(taskItems);
```